# Visual Studio 2010 Performance Analysis and Silverlight 4 OOB Apps

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 and creating an Out of Browser Silverlight 4 application. There are some slow bits and I'd like to profile it, but whenever I try, the application loads, the profiler starts but exits almost immediately.  It reads:

```
Profiler started
Successfully attached to process: 2088
Exited from process: 2088
Collection file exited: c:\projects\SPASilverlight\sllauncher091213(3).vsp
Profiler exited
PRF0025: No data was collected. 
===================== Profiling Complete =====================
```

Is this not possible or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but one thing that drastically improves VS2010 performance (and hang ups) is disabling intellitrace (options)

Comment: Ah, thanks for this tip, it may help me!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run your app as out of browser with elevated permissions? I guess profiler might need more permissions so it can reflect/instrument.

Comment: Yes, the application requires elevated privileges (COM Interop), so this is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could try my steps to profile from command line:

http://www.nachmore.com/2010/profiling-silverlight-4-with-visual-studio-2010/

At the very least you'll get a more verbose error message that will help you determine what the problem is.